# regex regular expression for numbers

Tags: regex

what is the best way to build a regex for numbers between 10 and 240, and another one between 10 and 360?

Comment: Why are you even considering regex for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regexes are no good to deal with numbers. Unless this is the only alternative that you got, you should probably choose another solution.

**10-240**: `^(?:2(?:[0-3]\d|40)|1\d\d|[1-9]\d)$`

Explanation:

1. `^`: Anchor that match the beginning of the string
2. `(?`: Non-capturing group (more performant than capturing groups). I use those for alternation.
3. `2`: Literal character '2'
4. `[0-3]`: A single digit between 0 and 3.
5. `\d`: A single digit character (0-9)
6. `|`: Or

3-6. `2(?:[0-3]\d|40)`: A number that starts with 2 followed by 0-3 and any digit or literally '40'. That match 200-240

7. `|1\d\d`: Or one followed by two digits (0-9). That match 100-199.
8. `|[1-9]\d` : Or a digit between 1-9 followed by any digit (0-9). That match 10-99.
9. `$`: Anchor that match the end of the string.

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/rO4fZ0/1

**10-360**: `^(?:3(?:[0-5]\d|60)|[12]\d\d|[1-9]\d)$`

1. `3(?:[0-5]\d|60)`: Literal character 3 followed by 0-5 and any digit or literally 60. That match 300-360.
2. `|[12]\d\d`: Or one or two followed by two digits (0-9). That match 100-299.
3. `|[1-9]\d` : Or a digit between 1-9 followed by any digit (0-9). That match 10-99.

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/lD8oM4/1

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do so, is with a tester, http://regexr.com

Here is the RegEx for the 10 to 240 match.

```
^(([1-9][0-9])|(1[0-9][0-9])|(2[0-3][0-9])|(240))$
```

However, I do feel this is probably not the right tool of what you want to achieve.

Mike

Comment: Moral of the story - Always use a tester and test your RegExs'